# AWS S3 Permissions - Access Denied ON GetObjectUrl PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

putObject works well for me. But when I do a getObjectURL s3 responds with an Access Denied. Looked into different ways to set the policy, etc. Still no luck. Any help appreciated!

putObject code:

```
$this->load->library('aws');

$temporary_png_path = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sig') . $upload_data['file_ext'];

$document_s3_key = 'profile_pictures/'.$user->id.'/profile_'.$user->id.$upload_data['file_ext'];

$resource = fopen($upload_data['full_path'], 'r');

try{
    $aws_object=$this->aws->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'      => 'tbucket',
        'Key'         => $document_s3_key,
        'SourceFile'  => $resource,
        'Body' => $resource,
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg'
    ));
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $error = "Something went wrong saving your file.\n".$e;
    echo $error;
}
```

getObjectURL code:

```
$this->load->library('aws');
$profile_image = $this->aws->getObjectUrl('tbucket', 'profile_pictures/'.$user->id.'/'.'profile_'.$user->id.'.jpeg');
$this->data['image'] = ($profile_image == '')? "/public/images/avatar-large.jpg" : $profile_image;
```

AWS Permissions:

```
Authenticated Users => All Permissions enabled
```

Bucket Policy:

```
    {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policynumber",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmtnumber",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::number:user/t_master"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::tbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you displaying the image? If so, you need to provide an expires time in the third argument the getObjectUrl method. Otherwise, it won't pre-sign it, and no one will be able to see it unless you make the ACL of the object public-read.

Comment: How do you check if the request finds no object. It still seems to send me a link that can expire, even if there is no object by that key.

Comment: getObjectUrl() does not actually need to make a request to S3. If you want to find out if an object exists before generating the link, use the doesObjectExist() method.